# hibernation fail on compaq 510

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, compaq

I have been tried to command hibernate in ubuntu 12.04. but it's fail because not enough swap memory (or not). please help me, I'm using compaq 510, 26 GB hardisk (have Windows 7). and because of fail the loaded internet page become distorted sometime. help

Comment: Are you using encrypted home? If so, chances are your swap is also crypted thus hibernate wont work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your BIOS not getting along with Ubuntu, that's what was wrong with my Compaq. Go on your model's support page and try several BIOS firmwares (even older ones), see if they fix the problem. For example, mine only works with release 1.3, and fails to sleep with release 1.5 (the latest one).